# Splunk query to compare two fields and select value from 3rd field if the comparison match

Tags: compare, splunk

I am very new to splunk and need your help in resolving below issue.

I have two CSV files uploaded in splunk instance. Below mentioned is each file and its fileds.

1. Apple.csv

a.  A1 b.   A2 c.   A3

2. Orange.csv

a.  O1 (may have values matching with values of A3) b.  O2

My requirement is as below:

```
Select set of values of A1,A2,A3 and O2 from Apple.csv and Orange.csv  
where A1=”X” and A2=”Y”  and  A3 = O1
```

and  display the values in a table:

**A1    A2  A3**

X   Y   123

LP  HJK 222

X   Y   999

**O1    O2**

999 open

123 closed

65432   open

**Output**

**A1    A2  A3  O2**

X   Y   123 Open

X   Y   999 closed

Very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
source="apple.csv" OR source="orange.csv"
| eval grouping=coalesce(A3,O1)
| stats first(A1) as A1 first(A2) as A2 first(A3) as A3 first(O2) as O2 by grouping
| fields - grouping
```

Although I would think that considering the timestamp of the events might also be important...